# definite article after "and"

Tags: articles, definite-article, ellipsis, academic-writing

The sentence about general facts:

> Molecules are neutral particles made of two or more atoms bonded together.
> ***The** proton and **the** electron are parts of an atom.*

Can we remove article before electron?

> Molecules are neutral particles made of two or more atoms bonded together.
> ***The** proton and electron are parts of an atom.*

(Should decide which style is better for academic writing).

Comment: This is going to depend on context...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [usage of "both" and the indefinite article a/an](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104261/usage-of-both-and-the-indefinite-article-a-an) It  doesn't matter that much whether it is the definite or indefinite article.

Comment: @ColleenV, soo we can remove second article?

Comment: Thanks @MikeBrockington, I add context to the question.

Comment: Why are you using the singular? Most atoms have several protons and electrons: *Protons and electrons are parts of atoms.*

Comment: If you want to write it that way, you could say: "The proton and electron are parts of an atom."  Note how 'part' is now plural.

Comment: I would avoid using "the" as in: The apple is good for the health. or The lion is fine feline. There are two many parts whirling around for that usage.

Comment: Also, made **up** of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep both **the**'s for more parallel construction especially given academic writing:

> The proton and the electron are part**s** of an atom.

> **Protons and electrons** are **parts** of an atom.
> **Protons and electrons** are **parts of atoms**.